# Create a DB schema to document application's features dynamically

Tags: angular, database, nestjs

I have an application(frontend using Angular and BE using NestJS) and I need to create a documentation(tutorials) for all application's features. I need to make those tutorials/documentation pages dynamic not static in the UI so I need to create a DB schema and provide APIs for document CRUD operations in the BE.

So, is there any recommended database or can anyone share with me the best practices to create a dynamic tutorials? How the DB will be like? What is the type of data (blob, string, ...) and so on.
Also if there are a best practice to make such feature in UI.

Answer (score 1):

I think MongoDB is the DB you are looking for.

Since you are familiar with JS, this repo may help you a lot: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose